# How to force slot's type to be checked during make-instance?

Tags: types, runtime-error, common-lisp, clos

Let's say I have the following class declaration:

```
(defclass foo-class ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar
        :type list)))
```

When I create an instance of this class, `make-instance` won't check whether passed arguments satisfy types of slots. So, I can create "invalid" objects this way:

```
> (make-instance 'foo-class :bar 'some-symb)
#<FOO-CLASS {102BEC5E83}>
```

However, what I'd like to see is the behavior similar to the creation of an instance of a struct, where the types are checked:

```
(defstruct foo-struct
  (bar nil :type list))

> (make-foo-struct :bar 'some-symb)
;; raises contition:
;;
;; The value
;; SOME-SYMB
;; is not of type
;; LIST
;; when setting slot BAR of structure FOO-STRUCT
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Rainer's Answer is correct. I'd like to add that there is already a library that implements that behaviour – quid-pro-quo. You can find it at https://github.com/sellout/quid-pro-quo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Whether slot types are being checked or not is undefined for both structures and CLOS instances**.

Many implementations will do it for structures - but not all.

Few implementations will do it for CLOS instances - Clozure CL actually does it for example.

SBCL also can check CLOS slot types - when safety is high:

```
* (declaim (optimize safety))

NIL
* (progn
(defclass foo-class ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar
        :type list)))
(make-instance 'foo-class :bar 'some-symb))

debugger invoked on a TYPE-ERROR: The value SOME-SYMB is not of type LIST.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((SB-PCL::SLOT-TYPECHECK LIST) SOME-SYMB)
0]
```

**How to do it otherwise?**

This is kind of an advanced subject which probably needs some CLOS meta-object-protocol hackery. Two variants:

- define a method for SHARED-INITALIZE which checks the init arguments.
- define a metaclass for your class and a method on SET-SLOT-VALUE-USING-CLASS . But then you need to be sure that your implementation actually provides AND uses SET-SLOT-VALUE-USING-CLASS. This is a generic function, which is part of the MOP. Some implementations provide it, but some are only using it when requested (otherwise setting a slot may get a speed penalty).

For the latter here is self-built **SBCL** version to check types for writing slots:

First the metaclass:

```
; first a metaclass for classes which checks slot writes
(defclass checked-class (standard-class)
  ())

; this is a MOP method, probably use CLOSER-MOP for a portable version
(defmethod sb-mop:validate-superclass
           ((class checked-class)
            (superclass standard-class))
   t)
```

Now we check all slot writes for that metaclass:

```
; this is a MOP method, probably use CLOSER-MOP for a portable version    
(defmethod (setf sb-mop:slot-value-using-class) :before
              (new-value (class checked-class) object slot)
  (assert (typep new-value (sb-mop:slot-definition-type slot))
      ()
    "new value ~a is not of type ~a in object ~a slot ~a"
    new-value (sb-mop:slot-definition-type slot) object slot))
```

Our example class uses that metaclass:

```
(defclass foo-class ()
  ((bar :initarg :bar :type list))
  (:metaclass checked-class))
```

Using it:

```
* (make-instance 'foo-class :bar 42)

debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005605B3}>:
  new value 42 is not of type LIST
  in object #<FOO-CLASS {1004883143}>
  slot #<STANDARD-EFFECTIVE-SLOT-DEFINITION COMMON-LISP-USER::BAR>

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Retry assertion.
  1: [ABORT   ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

Answer (score 3):

The [sanity-clause](https://github.com/fisxoj/sanity-clause) library just merged a feature for this yesterday.

> Sanity clause is a data validation/contract library. You might use it for configuration data, validating an api response, or documents from a datastore. In a dynamically typed langauge, it helps you define clearly defined areas of doubt and uncertainty. We should love our users, but we should never blindly trust their inputs.
>
> To make use of it, you define schemas, which can be property lists with symbols for keys and instances of :class:`sanity-clause.field:field`

So:

```
(defclass person ()
     ((favorite-dog :type symbol
                    :field-type :member
                    :members (:wedge :walter)
                    :initarg :favorite-dog
                    :required t)
      (age :type (integer 0)
           :initarg :age
           :required t)
      (potato :type string
              :initarg :potato
              :required t))
     (:metaclass sanity-clause.metaclass:validated-metaclass))

;; bad dog:
(make-instance 'person :favorite-dog :nope)
; Evaluation aborted on Error converting value for field #<MEMBER-FIELD {1004BFA973}>: 
Value "NOPE" couldn't be found in set (WEDGE WALTER)

;; bad age:
(make-instance 'person :age -1 :favorite-dog :walter)
; Evaluation aborted on Error validating value -1 in field #<INTEGER-FIELD {1004BFF103}>:
* Value -1 didn't satisfy condition "must be larger than 0"

;; missing potato:
(make-instance 'person :age 7 :favorite-dog :walter)
; Evaluation aborted on A value for field POTATO is required but none was provided..

;; all OK:
(make-instance 'person :age 1 :favorite-dog :walter :potato "patate")
#<PERSON {10060371E3}>
```