# How to Specify the Type of a Class Slot

Tags: class, common-lisp

What is the meaning of the :type type-specifier on a slot in a defclass expression? It doesn't seem to work the same way as in defstruct:

```
* (defclass counter ()
    ((value :initform 0
            :type (integer 0 *)
            :accessor value)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS COMMON-LISP-USER::COUNTER>
* (defparameter *c* (make-instance 'counter))
*C*
* (value *c*)
0
* (decf (value *c*))
-1
* (value *c*)
-1
```

Why does `(decf (value *c*))` not produce an error?

Comment: http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Declarations-as-Assertions

Comment: How to force slot's type to be checked during make-instance?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51723992/how-to-force-slots-type-to-be-checked-during-make-instance

Comment: Consequences undefined (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm)